# Emacs -q error "Failed to initialize color list unarchiver"

Tags: error

When I run emacs -q I got the following error (on Mac OS) although emacs window still pops up.  Any idea?

```
% /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -q
2021-05-10 22:44:57.297 Emacs-x86_64-10_14[43625:9228583] Failed to initialize color list unarchiver: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _initForReadingFromData:error:throwLegacyExceptions:]: non-keyed archive cannot be decoded by NSKeyedUnarchiver" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _initForReadingFromData:error:throwLegacyExceptions:]: non-keyed archive cannot be decoded by NSKeyedUnarchiver}
```

Comment: Please do the same thing with `emacs -Q`, and confirm that you have the same problem. If you don't have the problem then the problem is in your site's startup file.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

delete `~/Library/Colors/Emacs.clr`, your Emacs will recreate it at the next startup.

This seems to have become a recurring issue for Emacs on macOS. See if the answers here help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52521587/emacs-error-failed-to-initialize-color-list-unarchiver-when-i-call-it-in-the-t